# Matlab - Access elements form each column using a vector containing the rows

Tags: matlab, row

y is **MxN** matrix with data. I need to take a specific element form each column when x (1xN vector) contains the row positions:

```
y(x(1),1)
y(x(2),2)
y(x(3),3)
y(x(4),4)
```

I search for a "Matlabic" way to do this, without a loop.

Of course `y(x,:)` is not the way. I thought of `y(x+[0:N:N*M-1])`.

Is there a more formal way?

Comment: This is a duplicate - I'll try find the original. Try `sub2ind`

Comment: In case that answer isn't clear enough `y(sub2ind(size(y), (1:size(y,1))', x)`

Comment: That answer is pretty unclear but y(sub2ind(size(y), x, 1:size(y,2))) is what I need. Thank you.

Comment: sorry there are exact duplicates, many, but I could not find them!

Comment: The question title was perfect though. Thanks again Dan